# How to create a new column in pandas dataframe with minutes before and after specific time?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe with datetime index at 1 minute intervals. I want to create a new column with minutes before and after specific hours during the day (midnight, 8 am and 4 pm). The timedelta column will be used to select only relevant data for further analysis. I need only +- 15 minutes before and after those specific times of the day.

The final dataframe with the new timedelta column should look like the one below.

```
                      col1       col2  m_before_after
time
2020-03-09 07:51:00  7912.18   82.055      -9
2020-03-09 07:52:00  7911.47   52.817      -8
2020-03-09 07:53:00  7905.07   74.685      -7
2020-03-09 07:54:00  7909.73   76.219      -6
2020-03-09 07:55:00  7915.82   29.569      -5
2020-03-09 07:56:00  7913.14   42.579      -4
2020-03-09 07:57:00  7915.58   55.427      -3
2020-03-09 07:58:00  7905.08  110.761      -2
2020-03-09 07:59:00  7901.86  103.715      -1
2020-03-09 08:00:00  7908.31  125.694       0
2020-03-09 08:01:00  7925.00   97.241       1
2020-03-09 08:02:00  7933.81  150.154       2
2020-03-09 08:03:00  7936.88  177.740       3
2020-03-09 08:04:00  7939.22  160.145       4
2020-03-09 08:05:00  7934.20   79.237       5
2020-03-09 08:06:00  7930.13  292.857       6
2020-03-09 08:07:00  7952.92  596.857       7
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Shift the time by 15 minutes, check if the hours `isin([0,8,16]` and minutes are `between(30,60)`.

Comment: For your specific example, this works, but I hardcoded year, month, day and hour. If you can generalize that part, this should work: `df['m_before_after'] = np.clip((df.index - pd.Timestamp(year=2020, month=3, day=9, hour=8)).total_seconds() / 60, -15, 15)`